# Visual Studio Extensibility point for new files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

I need to replace default naming convention in Visual Studio 2012 for aspx\ascx files. Is there a way I can do it?

As one of possible solution, I thought that I can make Extension that will subscribe to some Visual Studio 2010\2012 extension point to replace old naming convention to new one. But is there a way to intercept file creation?

Comment: Creating a new `Project Template` doesn't help?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/s365byhx(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Creating project templates helped?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. It's not the same as I wanted, because we I'd like to handle it more globally. But anyway I think it could helps. Thank you. You can make your comment as answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Item templates has one nice thing - Wizards. It should be that thing that we neeeded. Thank you :)

Comment: Good to know that. Added it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new `Project Template` might help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/s365byhx(v=vs.100).aspx